# Pushing personnel repository (member of organization)

Tags: github

I recently joined a new company. They added me as a member of their organization on `Github`. (I'm using my personnel account)

Since then, I can't push to my personnel repositories anymore.

```
remote: Permission to *****/*******.github.io.git denied to pvp-***.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/********/****.github.io.git/': 
The requested URL returned error: 403
```

How can I keep continue using my personnel account pushing on my repositories and to my organizations' repositories ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check how your credentials are cached and used by Git when you are pushing.

For instance, with [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), that would use the [Windows Credential Store](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306541) (through the [GCM: Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) ), which might have stored a different login/password.

See more at [Git Credential Storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage).
Check your `git config -l` for a `credential.helper` configuration.